# error while installing ros groovy on ubuntu 12.04 arm

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I installing the ros  groovy on ubuntu 12.04 following the wiki page http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/UbuntuARM
I have steup the sources.list and the keys. Then `$sudo apt-get update` always show: `W:Failed to fetch http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros/dists/precise/Release`
.In fact, the website can be open.If I install the ros ignore the problem,
$sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ros-base  `it will show ：`
E：unable to locate packages ros-groovy-ros-base`
Please help me slove the problem,thank you very much.

Detailed process is as follows:

```
$sudo apt-get update
Hit http://packages.namniart.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://packages.namniart.com precise Release
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release
Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [50.7 kB]
Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [98.7 kB]
Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [50.7 kB]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise Release
Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [98.7 kB]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main armel Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe armel Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [112 kB]
Get:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [33.0 kB]
Get:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main armel Packages [328 kB]
Get:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe armel Packages [89.1 kB]
Get:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [479 kB]
Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [111 kB]
Get:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main armel Packages [698 kB]
Get:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe armel Packages [229 kB]
Get:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3564 B]
Get:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2850 B]
Get:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main armel Packages [328 kB]
Get:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe armel Packages [89.1 kB]
Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
Get:24 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main armel Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe armel Packages
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
Get:25 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main armel Packages [698 kB]
Get:26 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe armel Packages [229 kB]
Get:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3564 B]
Get:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2850 B]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Get:29 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [145 kB]
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Get:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [145 kB]
Fetched 4025 kB in 46s (86.0 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.namniart.com/repos/ros/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-armel/Packages')
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

$sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ros-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-ros-base
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196093/error-while-installing-ros-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.04-arm/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-10-28**:
I'm getting a 404 on the namniart URL as well. @ahendrix?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-28**:
That's funny.. it's trying to retrieve Release.In, when the filename should probably be InRelease. I'll do a little digging and see if I can figure out why that's happening.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-28**:
Scratch that; it was just a formatting error in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is apt getting a 404 error on that URL, or a different error? Please edit your question to include the full error message.

Are you using a soft-float (armel) or hard-float (armhf) version of Ubuntu?(soft-float is no longer supported).

Were you able to retrieve the apt key in the previous step properly? If you weren't, there's probably something wrong with your network connection. If you were able to retrieve the apt key, then you may want to make sure that you don't have a typo in your sources.list.

**EDIT**

It looks like you're trying to use armel (soft-floating point EABI), which is no longer supported, and doesn't perform very well anyway. You should upgrade to an armhf version of Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-10-29**:
Thanks.It helped me a lot indeed.But is there a way can installing ros on the  armhf version of Ubuntu.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
The instructions for installing an armhf version of Ubuntu on your board will depend on which board you're using.

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-10-30**:
If I use the armel version of ubuntu go on.Can I install ros from  source on arm  according to this  page http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-30**:
It's possible to do a from-source build on armel, but it takes a few days to run the compilation, and there will be packages like PCL that can't be compiled because some boards don't have enough RAM.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-30**:
Your time will be better spent finding and installing an armhf version of Ubuntu or Linaro.